# How to represent the string in the form of nt where t is the substring repeated n times?

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching

I want to represent the string in the form of nt where t is the substring repeated n times if found. For Example: `aaaaa = 5a ,ababab= 3ab,abcdabcd = 2abcd.`

I am using the following code to find out this.

```
public class PatternMatch {
    public static boolean isPatternFound(char [] a){
        int len=0,j=0,k;
        String pattern;
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            len =0;
            String temp = new String(a,0,i+1);
            StringBuffer br= new StringBuffer(new String(a,0,i+1));
            j = temp.length();
            k=j;
            while(br.toString().matches(temp)&& k+j <= a.length){
                br = new StringBuffer(new String(a,k,j));
                if(k+j == a.length && br.toString().matches(temp))
                    len = k+j;
                k=k+j;
            }
            if(len == a.length)
                break;
        }
        if(len == a.length){
            System.out.println("Pattern = " + new String(a,0,j));
        return true;
        }else
            return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char arr[] = "abcdabcd".toCharArray();
        if(isPatternFound(arr)){
            System.out.println("Pattern found..");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Pattern not found..");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to do this which uses less time complexity and space complexity?

Comment: Regular expressions?

Comment: @ Steephen Thanks for replying. But I want to do it  without regular expression. Without regular expression is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach

```
int charLength = character array length;

if charLength is a prime Number greater than 2 
    then "No Pattern Match Found";

else if charLength is a composite number(non prime number)
    Find the factors for the length and put it in an array

else if charLength is 2
    Run the matching logic and then break

Repeat the below section until we have factors in our factors array
Run the matching logic by taking each factor at a time.
if match is found for a factor
    then n times is the product of remaining factors

Your matching logic method should accept character array and patternlength to be matched as parameters
```

Please see the examples below

```
**example 1**
char arr[] = "abcdabcd".toCharArray();
int charLength = 8;
/*charLength is not a prime number;
Factors of 8 are 2 and 4, so the different combinations here is 
two characters repeated 4 times or 4 characters repeated 2 times
isPatternFound is called twice */

Call the isPatternFound with factor 2
isPatternFound("abcdabcd", 2)
    pattern = "ab" - this should be arrived using the length 2 from the char array
    result = Match not found 

Call the isPatternFound with factor 4
isPatternFound("abcdabcd", 4)
    pattern = "abcd" - this should be arrived using the length 4 from the char array
    result = Match found
    n times = ( charLength / factor)
   (ie)  n times = 8/4 = 2



    **example 2**
char arr[] = "jackrabbitjackrabbitjackrabbit".toCharArray();
int charLength = 30;
/*charLength is not a prime number;
Factors of 30 are 2, 3, 5, 6, and 10 */

Call the isPatternFound with factor 2
isPatternFound("jackrabbitjackrabbitjackrabbit", 2)
    pattern = "ja" - this should be arrived using the length 2 from the char array
    result = Match not found 

Call the isPatternFound with factor 3
isPatternFound("jackrabbitjackrabbitjackrabbit", 3)
    pattern = "jac" - this should be arrived using the length 3 from the char array
    result = Match not found

Call the isPatternFound with factor 5
isPatternFound("jackrabbitjackrabbitjackrabbit", 5)
    pattern = "jackr" - this should be arrived using the length 5 from the char array
    result = Match not found

Call the isPatternFound with factor 6
isPatternFound("jackrabbitjackrabbitjackrabbit", 6)
    pattern = "jackra" - this should be arrived using the length 6 from the char array
    result = Match not found

Call the isPatternFound with factor 10
isPatternFound("jackrabbitjackrabbitjackrabbit", 10)
    pattern = "jackrabbit" - this should be arrived using the length 10 from the char array
    result = Match found
    n times = ( charLength / factor)
    (ie)  n times = 30/10 = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

In principle you wrote a solution, but it could be more straight forward:

```
public static String f(String s) {
    dividing:
    for (int d = s.length(); d >= 2; --d) {
        if (s.length() % d == 0) {
            int n = s.length() / d;
            String g = s.substring(0, n);
            for (int gi = 1; gi < d; ++gi) {
                //if (!g.equals(s.substring(gi * n, (gi + 1) * n))) {
                if (!g.regionMatches(0, s, gi * n, n)) {
                    continue dividing;
                }
            }
            return d + g;
        }
    }
    return "1" + s;
}
```